# Customizing the Sub-entries of the Index for a Key Person Entry

Tags: formatting, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

Consider the subsequent Index which is generated by the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

    \begin{document}
    \large
    \par Here are some words.\index{Person, Key@{\scshape{Person, Key}}! In the beginning {\bf EVENT 1}}
    \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc
    \par More words.\index{Person, Key@{\scshape{Person, Key}}! This is followed by {\bf EVENT 2}}
    \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc
    \par More words.\index{Person, Key@{\scshape{Person, Key}}! Later, we have {\bf EVENT 3}}
    \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc
    \par More words.\index{Person, Key@{\scshape{Person, Key}}! Continuing with {\bf EVENT 4}}
    \newpage abc
    \par More words.\index{Person, Key@{\scshape{Person, Key}}! So follows {\bf EVENT 5}}
    \newpage abc
    \par More words.\index{Person, Key@{\scshape{Person, Key}}! Later comes {\bf EVENT 6}}
    \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc
    \par More words.\index{Person, Key@{\scshape{Person, Key}}! Followed by {\bf EVENT 7}}
    \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc
    \par More words.\index{Person, Key@{\scshape{Person, Key}}! Then comes {\bf EVENT 8}}
    \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc
    \par More words.\index{Person, Key@{\scshape{Person, Key}}! Shortly thereafter Event 8 comes {\bf EVENT 9}}
    \newpage abc 
    \par More words.\index{Person, Key@{\scshape{Person, Key}}! The end: {\bf EVENT 10}}
      
    
    \idxlayout{columns=1}
        \renewcommand\indexname{\color{RoyalRed}Index}
    %\renewcommand\indexname{Index.}
        \printindex
    \end{document}
```

[image]

What I would like to do, is to simply arrange the sub-entries in chronological order so that the sub-entry containing **EVENT 1** comes first, followed by the sub-entry containing **EVENT 2**, and so forth, all the way up to the one that contains **EVENT 10**. This way, also, the associated pages will appear in ascending order.

How may I accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
\index{Person, Key@\textsc{Person, Key}!\NOOP{<number>}<description>}
```

where `<number>` is autogenerated and `\NOOP` is a macro that does nothing, but is recorded in the `.idx` file. The number is padded to five digits with zeros, so it will be used for sorting.

Any “Person, Key” pair defines a counter that's incremented at each usage. Of course, we'll use a macro for automating the process.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NOOP}{m}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\personevent}{mm}
 {
  \mlchristians_personevent:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mlchristians_personevent:nn
 {
  \int_if_exist:cF { g_mlchristians_personevent_#1_int }
   {
    \int_new:c { g_mlchristians_personevent_#1_int }
   }
  \int_gincr:c { g_mlchristians_personevent_#1_int }
  % emit the index entry
  \index{ #1 @ \textsc{#1}! \NOOP { \__mlchristians_pad:n { #1 } } #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__mlchristians_pad:n
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { 5 - \tl_count:v { g_mlchristians_personevent_#1_int } } { 0 }
  \int_use:c { g_mlchristians_personevent_#1_int }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_count:n { v }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Here are some words.\personevent{Person, Key}{In the beginning \textbf{EVENT 1}}

\newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc

More words.\personevent{Person, Key}{This is followed by \textbf{EVENT 2}}
\newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc

More words.\personevent{Person, Key}{Later, we have \textbf{EVENT 3}}

\newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc

More words.\personevent{Person, Key}{Continuing with \textbf{EVENT 4}}

\newpage abc

More words.\personevent{Person, Key}{So follows \textbf{EVENT 5}}

\newpage abc

More words.\personevent{Person, Key}{Later comes \textbf{EVENT 6}}

\newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc

More words.\personevent{Person, Key}{Followed by \textbf{EVENT 7}}

\newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc

More words.\personevent{Person, Key}{Then comes \textbf{EVENT 8}}

\newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc \newpage abc

More words.\personevent{Person, Key}{Shortly thereafter Event 8 comes \textbf{EVENT 9}}

\newpage abc 

More words.\personevent{Person, Key}{The end: \textbf{EVENT 10}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Please, note that `\textsc{text}` is the correct syntax instead of `{\scshape{text}}` and that `\bf` has been deprecated for 25 years.

[image]

The `.idx` file is

```
\indexentry{Person, Key@\textsc  {Person, Key}!\NOOP {00001}In the beginning \textbf  {EVENT 1}}{1}
\indexentry{Person, Key@\textsc  {Person, Key}!\NOOP {00002}This is followed by \textbf  {EVENT 2}}{4}
\indexentry{Person, Key@\textsc  {Person, Key}!\NOOP {00003}Later, we have \textbf  {EVENT 3}}{9}
\indexentry{Person, Key@\textsc  {Person, Key}!\NOOP {00004}Continuing with \textbf  {EVENT 4}}{16}
\indexentry{Person, Key@\textsc  {Person, Key}!\NOOP {00005}So follows \textbf  {EVENT 5}}{17}
\indexentry{Person, Key@\textsc  {Person, Key}!\NOOP {00006}Later comes \textbf  {EVENT 6}}{18}
\indexentry{Person, Key@\textsc  {Person, Key}!\NOOP {00007}Followed by \textbf  {EVENT 7}}{21}
\indexentry{Person, Key@\textsc  {Person, Key}!\NOOP {00008}Then comes \textbf  {EVENT 8}}{25}
\indexentry{Person, Key@\textsc  {Person, Key}!\NOOP {00009}Shortly thereafter Event 8 comes \textbf  {EVENT 9}}{32}
\indexentry{Person, Key@\textsc  {Person, Key}!\NOOP {00010}The end: \textbf  {EVENT 10}}{33}
```

The `.ind` file is

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item \textsc  {Person, Key}
    \subitem \NOOP {00001}In the beginning \textbf  {EVENT 1}, 1
    \subitem \NOOP {00002}This is followed by \textbf  {EVENT 2}, 4
    \subitem \NOOP {00003}Later, we have \textbf  {EVENT 3}, 9
    \subitem \NOOP {00004}Continuing with \textbf  {EVENT 4}, 16
    \subitem \NOOP {00005}So follows \textbf  {EVENT 5}, 17
    \subitem \NOOP {00006}Later comes \textbf  {EVENT 6}, 18
    \subitem \NOOP {00007}Followed by \textbf  {EVENT 7}, 21
    \subitem \NOOP {00008}Then comes \textbf  {EVENT 8}, 25
    \subitem \NOOP {00009}Shortly thereafter Event 8 comes \textbf  {EVENT 9}, 
        32
    \subitem \NOOP {00010}The end: \textbf  {EVENT 10}, 33

\end{theindex}
```

Comment: This works perfectly when the index sub-entry occurs on one page in the document. However, if I want the citation spans a set of pages, say 6-9, then using, for example,  \personevent{Person, Key}{citation}|(} followed later in the document by \personevent{Person, Key}{citation}|)} would print out two separate sub-entries: Person, Key, 6 followed underneath by Person, Key, 9. Is there a way to print one sub-entry indicating a span of pages, such as the way noted which works for \index? Many thanks again for all your help.